# Web scraping of links to pdf files does not work

Tags: html, .net, web-scraping, f#

I have tried to scrape links to pdf files (`https://kodis-files.s3 .....`) from a webpage, but without any success.

I use F#, but I hope those coding in other .NET languages will find the code not hard to read.

I have used these two approaches (the code has been simplified with results to be printed rather than used elsewhere):

```
    //*******************************************
    let url0 = "https://www.kodis.cz/lines/region?tab=232-293"
    let document0 = HtmlDocument.Load(url0)

    document0.CssSelect("div#__next") 
    |> List.iter (fun item ->
                            let querySelector (tag: string) = (item.Descendants tag)                           
                            (querySelector "a")
                            |> Seq.iter (fun item ->      
                                                   let url = item.AttributeValue "href"
                                                   printfn "%s" url
                                        )           
                 ) 

    //*******************************************
    let url = "https://www.kodis.cz/lines/region?tab=232-293" 
    let document = HtmlDocument.Load(url)

    let links =
       document.Descendants "a"
       |> Seq.choose (fun x ->
                             x.TryGetAttribute("href")
                             |> Option.map (fun a -> x.InnerText(), a.Value())
                     ) |> Seq.toList   

    printfn "%A" links
```

**Both variants scrape all links on the website** **EXCEPT for the links to the pdf files**.

The link to the webpage in question is in the code. I have extracted part of the html code that is relevant to my problem.

```
<div id="__next" data-reactroot="">
    <!-- many "a hrefs" with links to various stuff -->
    <main class="mt-16">
        <div class="container">         
            <div class="mb-12">
                <ul class="mb-8 grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-2">
                    <li class="Card_wrapper__ZQ5Fp">                        
                        <div class="Card_actions__HhB_f">
                            <a href="https://kodis-files.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/232_2022_12_11_2023_12_09_d02eef94bc.pdf" target="_blank" class="Button_main__pEB6O Button_secondary__R6QEg Button_md__1RLR1" data-testid="button-elementAnchor" title="Pravidelný jízdní řád">                              
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="Card_wrapper__ZQ5Fp">                        
                        <!-- another "a href" with a link to a pdf file -->                         
                    </li>
                    <li class="Card_wrapper__ZQ5Fp">
                        <!-- another "a href" with a link to a pdf file -->
                    </li>                   
                </ul>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

**What do I do wrong?** Is it possible that some "anti-scraping" SW is employed by the creator of the website?

**EDIT:**
As Jim Foye suggested, the pdf links seem to be created by *JavaScript* and therefore not possible to be scraped with the help of `FSharp.Data` or `HtmlAgilityPack` or `.Net.WebClient` or `.Net.Http.HttpClient` or `wget`. If the only solution to this problem is to get the html code the same way as browsers save the code, please see [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75924785/how-can-i-get-html-code-that-is-shown-in-a-browser-programmatically). If not, please suggest the solution here.

Comment: Is the HTML segment you show taken from the HTML loaded by HtmlDocument.Load(), or did you copy it from a browser?

Comment: From the browser - not from the "Page Source", but using Chrome DevTools -> Elements

Comment: I am probably starting to understand where the problem is - HTML loaded by HtmlDocument.Load() does not contain the links to the pdf files. As far as I understand it, scraping this way is not possible to get the pdf links - so to get the links, I'll probably have to use some other method if at all possible.

Comment: Check the actual HTML that you get when you do the request with HtmlDocument.Load(). That's HtmlAgilityPack, right? I haven't used that, but there should be a way to look at what text it pulled down. See if the links are in there.

Comment: Yeah we posted our comments at the same time. One thing you have to look out for is that a request you make programmatically may actually return something different than what the browser gets, because the headers (in particular the user agent info) is different. In this case, though, I think the problem is the PDF links are being populated by the JavaScript in the page.

Comment: Well, yeah, HtmlDocument.Load() acts differently than I expected. So it cannot be helped - probably the only way to get the links to the pdf files is to manually save the relevant pages and scrape them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in the linked question that you found a way to do this. If you can find how the page is generated by JavaScript (as you did) then fetching the data directly is optimal.

However, in cases this does not work, there is also a nice F# library canopy that lets you automate a browser - so you can get the page loaded in the browser and then extract the links:

```cs
#r "nuget:canopy"
open canopy
open canopy.classic

// Download chromedriver.exe from
// https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
canopy.configuration.chromeDir <- "c:/temp/driver"

start chrome
url "https://www.kodis.cz/lines/region?tab=232-293"
```

You can run the above interactively in F# Interactive, wait until the page loads & run the following:

```cs
for el in elements "a" do
  let href = el.GetAttribute("href")
  if href.EndsWith("pdf") then
    printfn "%A" href
```

EDIT April 7, 2023 ***********************************

If you do not run the code in FS Interactive, you will probably need to add code like this one before the `for` loop:

```
let linksShown () = (elements ".Card_wrapper__ZQ5Fp").Length >= 11 
 //a condition for waitFor  
   
compareTimeout <- 10.0 //probably needed for slow connections

waitFor linksShown  //waiting until the needed number of elements are downloaded
```

Also check out for other Canopy stuff such as `waitforElement`.

End of EDIT**********************************************

This may also be useful if the page only loads data progressively. For example, you can simulate click on the "Další" button on the page to load more data:

```
click (elementWithText "a" "Další")
```

Comment: Yes, your code works :-). I haven't known about canopy so far. Well, actually, for your code to work with my slow internet connection, I had to add compareTimeout and waitFor (condition). May I add it into your answer?

Comment: Nice! I was looking at https://playwright.dev/ as a possible solution for this question but then gave up when I noticed Miroslav asked the other question. I'll have to play around with canopy.

Comment: @MiroslavHusťák Of course, please edit the answer to add this! (I only used it interactively in F# Interactive, so I waited "manually".)