# How can I get html code that is shown in a browser programmatically?

Tags: html, .net, google-chrome, opera

Using .NET, how can I get the html code that is shown in a browser (and that can be saved from browsers such as Chrome or Opera through Save As commands) **programmatically**?

Using `HtmlDocument.Load()` or `wget` is to no avail - I will not get what I want.

See also the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922303/web-scraping-of-links-to-pdf-files-does-not-work).

**EDIT**

Unfortunatelly the `.Net WebClient` (or rather the new `.Net.Http.HttpClient`) class did not help (see the answer by *bdcoder*). I got the same result as with `HtmlDocument.Load()` or `wget`. Not the html code that the browsers save.

```
let myHtml =         
    async 
        {     
            let client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
            let! responseBody = 
                client.GetStringAsync("https://www.kodis.cz/lines/region?tab=232-293")
                |> Async.AwaitTask
            return responseBody
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the network panel of the browser dev tools you can see the endpoint the JavaScript is calling to get the PDF data. You can use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) to request the same data then parse the JSON to get the pdf links.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it. This is what I needed. Although my browser dev tools window looks differently, I easily found the the link to the json data and using the code in my question, I got them. Parsing through the json data is not a problem.

Comment: Actually, parsing through the json data is not a problem when using the json type provider. Were the type provider not existed, I would not have the slightest idea of how to do it elegantly (splitting the json text does not look elegant to me - I have already tried).

Comment: `System.Text.Json` should be all you need to parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [.Net WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0) class?  You should be able to fetch a page from any URL, save the result and then process the HTML code accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. Please see the EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution to my problem is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922303/web-scraping-of-links-to-pdf-files-does-not-work) (an answer by Tomáš Petříček).